# Change transitionOut fancybox's object

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fancybox

Is it possible to set the object of the transitionOut to be different from the transitionIn one?

Regards,
Elkas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use
     $.fn.fancybox.defaults = {
      transitionIn: 'transitionName',
      transitionOut: 'transitionName'
     };